can't connect to my local when doing hello world on rustc
solana program deploy C:\Users\kamba\OneDrive\"Рабочий стол"\blockchain_assignment_2\solana-hello-world-local

Error: RPC request error: cluster version query failed: error sending request for url (http://localhost:8899/): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: The connection was not established because The destination computer rejected the connection request. (os error 10061)

My pc denies the request. Found answers for 101 os error but none for mine.
Everything looks fine. A also tried deploying in WSL ubuntu, but it did not work anyway
PS C:\Users\kamba\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\blockchain_assignment_2\solana-hello-world-local> solana config set --url localhost
Config File: C:\Users\kamba\.config\solana\cli\config.yml
RPC URL: http://localhost:8899
WebSocket URL: ws://localhost:8900/ (computed)
Keypair Path: C:\Users\kamba\.config\solana\id.json
Commitment: confirmed


And how do you run your Solana local validator? Is it running at the default port?

Be sure to get your test validator up and running first by executing the following in a separate window:
solana-test-validator

